# Why Navier-Stokes solutions are expected to be $C^\infty$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, conjectures

I am curious, why the Millennium problem about Navier-Stokes is about smooth ($C^\infty$) not just $C^1$ solutions?